# Why is ScrollView creating a gap in my activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I used the following code to display a series of image Buttons vertically. I can successfully scroll through the images that I created but there's a gap in the middle of the screen that I can't fix. I believe that the error stems from the LinearLayout I used but switching that out with a relative or contained layout that didn't change anything.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/homepbckrnd">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/facebook" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="229dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ddrr" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_poll_black_24dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/google" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ddrr" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/facebook" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/facebook" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: The gap][image: Everything past the gap]

Comment: remove `android:layout_marginTop="229dp"` in your `imageButton2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `android:layout_marginTop="229dp"` from your `imageButton2` as by doing that you are applying a top margin of 229dp on your image which is causing this issue for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :)